# I want to save an object in storage. Which approach is better and faster, serialization or using gson?

Tags: android, serialization, gson

I want to save an object to storage. Initially I was using serialization, but whenever the object changes, I had an issue with de-serialization. So I have introduced serialVersionUID manually and I don't have any trouble now. I want to know if there are any other approaches other serialization, which are better and faster. Is it true that Gson is faster than serialization? Is it true that we won't have any issues during de-serialization with Gson even if the object changes?

Answer (score 0):

For Mobile Database use `Realm Database`

> https://realm.io/products/realm-database/

and for parsing JSON use `GSON converter and Retrofit` to populate the data.

Comment: well, I am not looking to store data on some third party database. I am looking for options to save data locally in android device.